# Spring Security: How to clear `remember me` cookie programmatically?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using logout method in web-app like below, but if i check `remember me` logout doesn't work, because cookie isn't cleared. How to clear programmatically this cookie in my method (or how to make better logout method) ?

```
public void logout() {
    AnonymousAuthenticationToken anonymous = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken("anonymous", "anonymous", new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"))));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(anonymous);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the standard Spring Security cookie name (which is `SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE`), you can do this:

```
void cancelCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
  String cookieName = "SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE";
  Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, null);
  cookie.setMaxAge(0);
  cookie.setPath(StringUtils.hasLength(request.getContextPath()) ? request.getContextPath() : "/");
  response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

You'll have to change the `cookieName` value if you are using a custom cookie name.

Comment: How to get request and response ? Nothing in Spring to clear that ?

Comment: Just pass them into your controller: `public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {`. Spring MVC will automatically pass them in.

Answer (score 2):

The `AbstractRememberMeServices` class has an implementation of `LogoutHandler.logout` which cancels the cookie. Inject the `LogoutHandler` and call this method.