# Spring security is not deleting remember me cookie when I logout

Tags: spring-security, java-ee-6

I have a login page with a remember me checkbox when i actually checkbox and login it works and creates the cookie for me logging in the problem is when I logout it redirects me just fine but for some reason it keeps the rememberMe Cookie active so when I get back into the application from another page it immediately logs me in

What are some things I can look so that I can delete the cookie when i logout.

Comment: looks like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265490/spring-security-how-to-clear-remember-me-cookie-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to configure your custom logout page if it differs from '/j_spring_security_logout'.

```
<http>
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout.htm"/>
</http>
```

Specifying 'logout-success' parameter you say Spring that it have to delete the cookie after request with such address.
NOTE: any code mapped to this link ('/logout.htm') will be never executed 'cause of standard spring filters.