# spring remember me logoff taking user to secure page instead of login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, remember-me

i am trying to make user to stay at login page when he does logoff but user is redirecting back to secured url , since i have remember me filter for my login url.

i want user stay at login page after logout.

```
<http pattern="/menu/logOff" entry-point-ref="customEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter ref="logOutFilter" position="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
</http>

<http pattern="/menu/login" entry-point-ref="customEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER" ref="rememberMeFilter" />
</http>
```

but when i click logoff it goes to login page and taking to secured page since i have remember filter to login page. is there any way to stay at login when user logoff?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Security: How to clear \`remember me\` cookie programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265490/spring-security-how-to-clear-remember-me-cookie-programmatically)

Comment: Why do you have 2 http blocks with a single filter and matching a single url? This is very weird. Also, all filters seem custom. How can anyone know what's wrong without knowing any of the code? Are you just trying to invalidate the cookie on log-off?

Comment: yes i am invalidating session and cookie during logoff, on two urls are different and they have different filters